# i want to add string data to before first character and after last character

Tags: php, string

Shortly i have string variable similar to this:(every li elements is array element.)

```
<li>first</li>
<li>second</li>
.
.
.
```

I want get:

```
<ul>
<li>first</li>
<li>second</li>
    .
    .
    .
</ul>
```

But require add string data's start and end for this avaible..

Comment: I think you can benefit from reading the manual section about strings, it shows you how to do such and similar things, it's worth to know: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$var = "<ul>\n".$oldvar."\n</ul>";
```

will probably does it

Comment: @Rikudo nice :) PHP tag is really very competitive

Answer (score 3):

This one's easy.

```
$str = "<li>.....</li>\n"
$strWithUL = "<ul>\n$str</ul>";
```

Hidden in plain sight :)

Comment: That's probably what OP is concerned about, according to the expected output given in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Not really?

```
$my_string = "foo";
$new_string = "<start>" . $my_string . "<end>";

// $new_string is now "<start>foo<end>"

// or, another option:
$new_string = "<start>$my_string<end>";
```